# How lazy is InverseProperty property

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have 2 entities: `Post` and `Comment`

I have a `Post` instance and I want to get its first 10 comments.

`Post`:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Post")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

`Comment`:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

How many Comments will come **from the database** if I do this? All or just 10?

```
var comments = post.Comments.Take(10).ToList();
```

Is it more efficient to do this?

```
var comments = Db.Comments.Where(x => x.Post == post).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: Why not trying out before asking?

Comment: I don't know how to check this.

Comment: You got the code above, populate the db, execute it make a breakpoint, check the values. In the time you spent writing if its possible you could have tested it 10 times already

Comment: Check what values? ICollection is just an interface. You don't know its implementation. It could be lazy.

Comment: So what? once you enumerate it, it will be loaded. Also only the old EF has lazy loading, EF Core doesn't have it at all

Comment: EF core doesn't have lazy loading? Does it mean that whenever I get a Post from the database I also get all its comments? It sounds so broken that it's hard to believe. Do you have any source of this information?

Comment: No, when you get post, the comments will be empty/null unless you do eager loading (`.Using`, or the comment is involved in the projection or you use `.Load` method, see docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `.Include()` then the property with `InverseProperty` attribute will contain all `Comments` assigned to this `Post`.

So it's better not to use it if you want to get only the first 10 comments.